# Is it safe to remove values from a dictionary while iterating in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

So my code hasn't crashed, but this feels like it shouldn't be safe, but I can't find a clear answer in the swift docs. I'm iterating over a dictionary with a `for-in` loop and removing those elements if not found in a reference array. I'm wondering if this is safe, and if so, why?

```
    func cleanupETADictionary(trips: [Int64]){
        for (tripId, _) in etaDictionary{
            if !trips.contains(tripId){
                etaDictionary.removeValue(forKey: tripId)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should be fine... why should it be not safe?

Comment: From a dictionary point of view, it should be safe because 'removeValue' will return nil if no key is found. It may hinder performance if you have an extremely long array / dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iteration does not work like you're thinking it does. Your iterated `etaDictionary` is a ***copy*** of the original. Dictionaries are value types in Swift.

Clear example:

```swift
var dictionary = [1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5]

for kvp in dictionary {
  dictionary = [:]
  print(kvp)
  print(dictionary.count)
}
```

outputs:

```swift
(key: 5, value: 5)
0
(key: 3, value: 3)
0
(key: 4, value: 4)
0
(key: 1, value: 1)
0
(key: 2, value: 2)
0
```

There's a name for your for loop, though; it is called `filter`. Use it instead.

```swift
func cleanupETADictionary(trips: [Int64]){
  etaDictionary = etaDictionary.filter { trips.contains($0.key) }
}
```

Comment: Now what if you print dictionary.count after the for loop completes in your example?

Comment: Also I don't know that a filter would work. The trips array is an array of trips that I _want_ to keep. So basically I want to tell a dictionary of n elements to keep this set of elements and get rid of the rest.